# How to convert .tif to .pix or .gpr or open a .tif file in Focus

Tags: fme-form, raster-conversion, geotiff-tiff

I was wondering if anyone knows how to convert a raster .tif file into some thing that PCI Geomatica (Focus) can use, such as a .pix or .gpr file?

I have tried to run it through FME, but I cannot seem to come up with a transformer that lets me do it.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a way to open a .tif file in Focus, as it already is in RGB?

Comment: Can your software read http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pcidsk.html or PCI aux http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the PCI Geomatics Database File (PCIDSK) format in FME.

That's a raster format that writes .pix files. I don't know that format well enough to be sure, but it seems the logical format to try.

[image]